# monitor goes blank opening google chrome download page

Tags: nvidia

Now this is trully a esoteric problem.

I have a Dell Vostro 1710 and freshly installed ubuntu 14.04.1

Whenever I try to open google.com/chrome monitor turns off. I can't even switch to the console. The computer still works. On my testing I've left a terminal ready to reboot and, even without the monitor I can alt-tab into it and reboot.

This computer has a nvidia card

I don't even know were to begin to debug this. It just happens on that particular page. anyone can think of a reason for this to happen?

Thank you all

Comment: If "It just happens on that particular page" then you don't have any problem about Nvidia card. And also did you test on another browsers?

Comment: ok, some more updates. It's not an Nvidia card, it's an INTELL gm965/GL960 and it happens with firefox and chrome. Opera works fine.

Comment: What is the result of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay` in terminal?

Comment: uint32 300
It's a mozilla thing. Should be some head bump between my graphics card and the hardware acceleration or something. I have disabled it, but still behaves the same way

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue. In a duplicate of this question ([Whenever I go to the google chrome download page my laptop screen turns off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538535/whenever-i-go-to-the-google-chrome-download-page-my-laptop-screen-turns-off)), NickT suggested to check in `/var/log/syslog`, where a GPU crash is noticed. Apparently, the user filed a bug report on https://bugs.freedesktop.org/, but I couldn't find it.

```
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.804089] [drm] stuck on render ring
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.804099] [drm] GPU crash dump saved to /sys/class/drm/card0/error
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.804101] [drm] GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace.
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.804102] [drm] Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.804104] [drm] drm/i915 developers can then reassign to the right component if it's not a kernel issue.
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.804105] [drm] The gpu crash dump is required to analyze gpu hangs, so please always attach it.
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.805115] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x55c8000 ctx 0) at 0x55c81cc
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  146.864080] [drm] GMBUS [i915 gmbus vga] timed out, falling back to bit banging on pin 2
Jan 26 22:24:57 zaczyn kernel: [  147.312076] [drm:i915_reset] *ERROR* Failed to reset chip.
```

Trying too look into `/sys/class/drm/card0/error` (as sudo), I get `no error state collected`. Reproduced the error, switch to a cmd with Alt+Tab unseen and dumped the file right after the error. Still the same content.

**Workaround**

Google support described a workaround (i.e. installing google-chrome from the command line) under https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/hOUs6FH35tg, which allowed me at least to install google chrome (and open the chrome download page :P).

**Edit**
Tried to disable the hardware acceleration in Firefox, considering the apparent GPU involvement. But it did not help.

**Edit**
Other possible solutions can found searching for `stuck on render ring`, mainly concerning changing accelmethod back to uxa.