# Whenever I go to the google chrome download page my laptop screen turns off

Tags: screen, browser, crash

I can't recover from the screen being off without resetting the laptop using the power button.

When I use the fn+volume keys while the screen is off I can hear the volume changing, I just can't find a way to get the screen to come back on.

I am using a Samsung Q45 laptop. I can pull any debug/system info and paste it in if someone tells me the commands to run.

Here is the link that crashes (crashes in both Firefox and Chromium):
[www.google.com/chrome/browser](http://www.google.com/chrome/browser)

Comment: I can conform such things happen: when I open Google Maps in Chrome, sometimes intel video driver crushes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the contents of the file /var/log/syslog 
Each line starts with a timestamp.  Find the section that coincides with the time the screen goes blank and see if you can find any relevant entries.
I experienced a similar problem and the entries in my syslog file started...
*(timestamps at start of each line removed for clarity)*

```
 [drm] stuck on render ring
 [drm] GPU crash dump saved to /sys/class/drm/card0/error
 [drm] GPU hangs can indicate a bug anywhere in the entire gfx stack, including userspace.
 [drm] Please file a _new_ bug report on bugs.freedesktop.org against DRI -> DRM/Intel
```

I posted a bug report at freedesktop.org  No fix yet but hopefully the bug report will help get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a workaround at the duplicate question [monitor goes blank opening google chrome download page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536466/monitor-goes-blank-opening-google-chrome-download-page), to at least download chrome via the command line.